# Does async offer any advantages when opening a page with Navigation.Push?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can someone explain to me what is the difference between:

```
void openPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Navigation.PushAsync(new CFSPage());
   // some code here
}
```

and

```
async void openPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CFSPage());
   // some code here
}
```

and

```
async void openPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new CFSPage());
   // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly straightforward difference between

```
void openPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Navigation.PushAsync(new CFSPage());
   // some code here 1
}
```

and

```
async void openPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new CFSPage());
   // some code here 2
}
```

In `some code here 1`, you *cannot* assume that the push has *completed*. So any code you write there cannot depend on it. In `some code here 2` you can assume the push is completed.

Whilst your code was waiting in option 2, it wasn't *blocking a thread*. Of course, you may in fact wish to combine these:

```
void openPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var abc = Navigation.PushAsync(new CFSPage());
   // some code here that doesn't depend on the push
   await abc
   // now the code that actually wants to rely on the push being complete
}
```

The first block of code had something *useful* to do with its thread, so it got on with that work. *If*, as it happens, when it reaches `await` and the push has completed by then, it will just carry on into the second block. Only if the push is still not complete at that point do we release our thread, which can hopefully have some work found for it to do elsewhere.

[Gerald's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51436252/15498) already addressed modal/non-modal

Answer (score 3):

Modal and not modal is what it says: it pushes a page modal, or it pushes a page on the regular navigation stack. Modal means a page that is shown in a more compelling way to the user. For instance, on iOS, it will not have a back arrow in the left corner. You, as the developer, will need to provide a way for the user to get out of a modal screen. This can be done by adding a custom button in most cases, but could also be triggered by the completion of a long-running operation.

For the await and not await portion of your question I would recommend to look into some resources on what await/async does. It can be a tough cookie to crack, but when you understand what it does and how to use it it can work to your advantage.

In this particular case it is probably used to not block the UI, so animations will look good. Also, the not awaited version will race over the push call before it might be completed which can cause unexpected behavior.